# What does OpenCL kernel execution time includes in OpenCL code?

Tags: opencl

I want to ask a simple question. Can time difference between creating OpenCL context and Executing OpenCL kernel be called kernel time in OpenCL code?  And is

> time_t start1,end1;

```
clock_t start2,end2; 

start1=time(NULL);  

start2=clock();
```

capable of calculating this time?

Answer (score 3):

Briefly - no. Right way to measure kernel time is to get OpenCL event, associated with kernel and collect profiling info. It's done like this:

```
cl_int ret;
cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &ret);
...  
cl_event my_event;
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, global_offset, global_size, local_size, num_events, wait_list, &my_event);
clWaitForEvents(1, &my_event);

cl_ulong start, finish;
ret =  clGetEventProfilingInfo(my_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(cl_ulong), &start, NULL);
ret =  clGetEventProfilingInfo(my_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(cl_ulong), &finish, NULL);

cl_ulong time_ns = finish - start;
```

`time_ns` is time in nanoseconds between kernel start & end. Don't forget to check return codes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. It worked well for my purpose Mr. Roman Arzumanyan.